# PHP/MySQL - how to UPDATE dynamically added rows

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, sql-update

I have a form which contains a part where the rows can be added dynamically by clicking on an 'add new row' button.

Each row has 2 fields: **Description** and **Completed Date**

This is the table I'm using to store the rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Contact ID',
parent_id int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parent ID',
description varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Description',
completed_date date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Completed date',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT='Example';
```

On my form, the fields are defined as arrays, so if there were 2 rows, the HTML would be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="description[0]" placeholder="Description">
<input type="text" name="completed_date[0]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
<input type="text" name="description[1]" placeholder="Description">
<input type="text" name="completed_date[1]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
```

I have no problem writing rows to the database using a loop, but I'm struggling to come up with the best way to **UPDATE** rows.

For example, if 2 rows are written to the database, then the user edits the form and changes the date on the second row, how do I know that I should be updating the second row on the database, not the first?

The only way I can think of is to add the 'id' field from the database as a hidden field on each row but my question is - is that the standard/best way to do it or is there some other trick I'm missing?

I could turn this in to a JSON field and store all the rows as a JSON object but I'd like to retain the ability to easily query the data.

**EDIT** - just thought of another way - delete all records and re-insert rather than update. Is that a better way to do it? Any opinions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, adding `id` as `hidden` field is your best bet to do this. Your form should look like this:

```
<form action="editwork.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id_of_this_row;?>"/>
<input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $desc_of_this_row;?>" placeholder="Description"/>
<input type="text" name="completed_date" value="<?php echo $comp_date_of_this_row;?>" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
<input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

Each loop item should generate different `<form>` tag for each row, thus different save button to update the row

**Recommended**: handle it with javascript so your page doesn't refresh everytime one simple row is updated.

**And**: Deleting records and re-inserting, is probably the worst way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

did you use last inserted id from mysql DB. order by inserted date.

Comment: not sure what you mean. I can find the last inserted id but not sure how that would help me? The user could insert 10 rows initially when creating the records

Comment: I got the meaning of your post. I don't know any special way. Most of case I do as you. are you using framework? may be there is special automated object class.